# Local variable scope when one function calls another inside bash shell

Tags: bash, function, shell

```
# ! /bin/sh

function pqr()
{
  # This prints value to 10 even though variable is local inside a
  echo "Displaying value of var a $a"  
}
function abc()
{
local a=10
# call function pqr and don't pass value of a
pqr
}
```

Even though I don't pass variable a to pqr() function I get a=10 inside pqr(). My question is is scope and visibility  of a  is same inside pqr() as that of abc() ?Is this because we are calling pqr() from function abc()?I was expecting new variable would get created inside pqr and will display blank value.(As this is how variable scope and visibility works inside modern languages so I am curious how this works inside bash )
I understood that In the above example If I re declare a inside pqr() then new variable will get created and hence displaying blank value. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "Is this because we are calling pqr() from function abc()?" - Yes :-)

Comment: The manual for `local` mentions "it makes the variable NAME have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children. "

Comment: Most modern languages are lexically scoped. `bash`, however, is dynamically scoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (from `man bash`):

> When `local` is  used within a function, it causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.

So calling `pqr` from within `abc` means that the variable `$a` is visible inside both functions.

It's worth mentioning that since you're using bash-specific features such as `local` and the non-portable `function` syntax, you should change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.